# Mass-change encoding of files/directories

Tags: files, sublime-text, encoding, utf-8

For some reason many files/directories on my server are not UTF-8 encoded. Is there a way I can change these files so they are utf-8? The majority of files on the server are UTF-8.

Is there a way I can mass-fix these files so that they will download with my text editor?

[image]

Comment: Related: https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/encoding-problem-with-sftp-and-syncing-folder/13301

Comment: Possibly: https://sourceforge.net/projects/cp-converter/

Comment: @EldgerGeek Have studied that carefully, no comments there helped me come to a solution. You can only set 1 remote encoding in the config file, this doesn't help me where I have files of multiple encodings

Comment: Could you define that which you have studied? Do you mean the forum post or the sourceforge project?

Comment: @ElderGeek Sorry I mean the forum post. I cannot use the sourceforge project as I am on a Mac, ideally I need to resolve this on the server directly. It's such a frustrating problem, I only want my text editor to download the files :'(

Comment: That was my understanding. Are you saying your server is a Mac?

Comment: No, sorry, the server is running Ubuntu and I'm working remotely on a Mac. It looks to me like that project is a Windows project? Correct me if I'm mistaken but I saw .exe files

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45460/discussion-between-elder-geek-and-jskidd3).

Answer (score 1):

The `iconv` program reads in text in one encoding and outputs the text in
       another encoding.  If no input files are given, or if it is given as  a
       dash (-), iconv reads from standard input.  If no output file is given,
       iconv writes to standard output.

```
   If no from-encoding is given, the default is derived from  the  current
   locale's  character  encoding.  If no to-encoding is given, the default
   is derived from the current locale's character encoding.
```

`iconv` is likely part of your default Ubuntu installation. You can confirm it's installed with the command `which iconv` the output will be the location of the program which in my case is `/usr/bin/iconv`

If for some reason you don't have it you can install it `sudo apt-get install libc-bin`

It seems that `iconv` is also available in OSX.

If you don't know the existing encoding you could try `file -i filename` for Ubuntu or `file -I filename` for OSX which should provided metadata including encoding.

Example:

```
$file -i netflix-backtrace.txt 
netflix-backtrace.txt: text/plain; charset=us-ascii
```

Sources:

`man iconv`

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64860/best-way-to-convert-text-files-between-character-sets

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/805418/how-to-find-encoding-of-a-file-in-unix-via-scripts